# IntelliJ IDEA+Maven+JUnit5

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, junit

Начал изучать данную связку.

В **pom.xml** кроме собственно **junit-jupiter** подключил еще через
**build-plugins-plugin** **maven-surefire-plugin** (с версией по умолчанию Junit5 не работал)

Тесты проходят, но не отрабатывается `@DisplayName` (Ну или я не знаю, куда у неё вывод по умолчанию).

При запуске тестов непосредственно из Идеи `Run 'All Tests'` всё проходит нормально.

Соответственно вопрос - что я в Мейвене не доконфигурировал?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59012529/2231972

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решился настройкой maven-surefire-plugin через найденный maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter.
(This is a dependency for maven-surefire-plugin, it adds a tree view for the unit tests executed using JUnit5.)

Answer (score 0):

@DisplayName отображается в выводе тестов, когда используется инфраструктура вывода тестов, поддерживаемая JUnit. Для того, чтобы это работало в Maven, необходимо настроить конфигурацию плагина maven-surefire-plugin. Для этого можно добавить следующий код в pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Также необходимо добавить следующую зависимость в pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-console</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

После этого перезапустите ваш проект и проверьте, что отображается @DisplayName в выводе тестов в Maven.